# why list clearing all elements in another list python3?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am writing code to group anagrams

```
strs=["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
ans=[]
ra=[]
for i in strs:
    if i in ra:
        continue
    for j in  strs:
        if sorted(i)==sorted(j):
            ra.append(j)

    ans.append(ra)
    ra.clear()
print(ans)
```

in the above code, it should print the anagram list but instead, it is printing empty list
why is ans list getting cleared?

Comment: because you keep appending *the same list* to `ans`, which you subsequently clear. i.e. `ans.append(ra)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ans` list is not getting cleared, but it is rather consisting of multiple references to `ra` which is an empty list, because after inserting the elements, you clear it with `ra.clear()`.

If you replace `ra.clear()` with `ra = []`, you should no longer clear out the `ra` list, but instead you will be creating a new object.
Another way of looking it is that `.clear()` is removing elements from the `list` pointed to by the name `ra`, and `ans.append(ra)` does not protect `ra` from further modification. Instead, by doing `ra = []` you ensure that `ra` points to a new object.

---

A simpler example to illustrate the issue:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a  # assign `b` to `a`

print(a)
# [1, 2, 3]
print(b)
# [1, 2, 3]

# we modify `a`
a[0] = 10
print(a)
# [10, 2, 3]

# also `b` gets modified
print(b)
# [10, 2, 3]

c = [a] * 4
print(c)
# [[10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3]]
a[0] = 1
print(c)
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
strs=["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
ans=[]
ra=[]
for i in strs:
    ra=[]
    if i in ra:
        continue
    for j in  strs:
        if sorted(i)==sorted(j):
            ra.append(j)
    ans.append(ra)
print(ans)
```

Also the `if i in ra: continue` is unnecessary. So it better to run:

```
strs=["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
ans=[]
ra=[]
for i in strs:
    ra=[]
    for j in  strs:
        if sorted(i)==sorted(j):
            ra.append(j)
    ans.append(ra)
print(ans)
```

And for why you got an empty list, Yes, @norok2 is right.